# Jquery window.scrollTo causes page to freeze

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

I'm redesigning a website that has a 100% screen-height header which needs to be shrunken to 0px when the user starts to scroll. The problem I have is after the header has shrunken to 0px, the content of the page is slightly above the top of the window. I've tried using "window.scrollTo(0,0)" after the header shrinks, which works, except I can't scroll anything after that. My page gets stuck at the top? Demo --> http://test-sandbox.000webhostapp.com

Does anyone have suggestions how to allow the page to keep scrolling? Or maybe a way to animate the header so that the content doesn't go past the top of the page?

Comment: You need to post your code here if you want help with it.

Comment: HTML ----> http://pastebin.com/mLaJzgvy  CSS ----> http://pastebin.com/UQbnyQL7

Comment: "here" means you put the code in the post, not a link to an external site.

Comment: Sorry about that. How can I do that with only 600 characters available?

Comment: [edit] your question to include the code as a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this is happening because of when you scroll and shrink the height of the header to 0, the height of the div #headerlogo is set to 160px. Setting the height to 150px did it for me. I tested this in the Chrome and it worked fine. The code that you provided worked as it should in Firefox and the transition was running weird in the IE. You should add proper transitions declarations for all browsers.

```
    -webkit-transition: background-color 500ms ease-out 1s;
    -moz-transition: background-color 500ms ease-out 1s;
    -o-transition: background-color 500ms ease-out 1s;
     transition: background-color 500ms ease-out 1s;
```

Comment: The provided code worked and the #headerlogo was fully in view at the top of the screen for you? I used the 160px as a hack for me because that's how far my mouse scrolls for each scroll-click of my middle wheel.

Comment: Yes, only in the Firefox. In Chrome there was extra space and setting the height to 150px !Important in the inspector before scrolling (https://www.screencast.com/t/uyYd2Q4uOa1) did it for me. And in the IE, the slider transitioned from top down and some of it was covered by the header-logo.

Comment: I forgot to mention, the page was not freezing while scrolling at any time and on all browsers.

Comment: Hmmm I'm getting different results on my end. This is how it renders currently http://i.imgur.com/hjCd8lA.png and this is how I would like it to render http://i.imgur.com/hjCd8lA.png . Notice the new item (#headerlogo) below the nav bar.

Comment: I think I uploaded a version without the jQuery scroll. Try it again now?